# How to display text and number side by side in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to achieve the required output

```
Total=20
```

but when i try

```
select 'total=',sum(score) from table;
```

it gives the output as

```
Total= 20
```

Comment: If you want to be in the same column you should do 
    select 'total=' **||** sum(score) from table;

Answer (score 2):

try it.

```
select 'total='||sum(score) from table
```